# laravel's Session flush and forget methods not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, session

I tried to delete a value from my session using :

```
Session::forget('value')
```

but it didn't delete!

However,  when i tried using `save` method like so :

```
 Session::forget('value')
 Session::save()
```

it worked!  (I.e. the value was deleted from the session.)

Please - what am I doing wrong?  I don't see the `save` method in the Laravel documentation when using `Session::flush()` and `Session::forget()`.

Comment: [Here's save, it's not in the documentation, but it is part of the interface](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Session/Store.html#method_save)

Comment: Session::save() is working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The save() method will actaully perform the write to the file.

It seems that your application doesn't call Session::save() before it outputs content to the user on all requests.

If this method isn't called, the Session file will not get updated with the new values, and they will still be there on the next visit.

It's important to always call Session::save() if you wish to be sure stuff got removed or added and the change persists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I was stuck with `Session::forget('key');` It was removing session key temporarily, but on the next request session key still, exists.
After Using `Session::save();` following forget() method, it permanently removed the session key

Answer (score 5):

Full cache clear (either using command-line or code):

```
php artisan cache:clear
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

+ Full session flush:

```
Session::flush();
```

through this method you can clear all of your session data.

Comment: While debugging with `dd($session)`, `Session::flush()` was not permanently clearing the sessions for me until I also called the `save()` method. (as the accepted answer suggests)

Answer (score 1):

i use `Session::save()` method its work fine to save session data. But when i flush session using `Session::flush()` it does not clear all the data that is stored in Laravel session. `Session::forget('value')` works fine to clear session specific value.